# Invoice printout

Tags: .net, printing

I am working on a application in .net.I want to do all calculation and then to print
all the information of the selected items on a given page of the company and then to
take the print of that page and also to save the same page in DB and send invoice to
the client through email in .pdf.
Please suggest.?

Comment: have you considerd XPS instead of PDF? they are much easier to generate since XPS is xml based

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is to late to the game, but this website [Simpeli](https://simpe.li) have some nice templates to choose from for generating good looking PDFs.

You make a PDF with a very simple API call.

Answer (score 0):

If you can spend some money on a report generator tool, have a look at the Xtra Reports from DevExpress: [Link](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/). This can export to pdf. Then I would take the generated file and store it (or a reference to it) in the database. For actually sending the mail you could use the MailMessage-Class in System.Net.Mail

Answer (score 0):

I would generate and store XML and have XSLT conversions to PDF, HTML, etc...
consider [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210222/converting-between-document-formats-in-c).

A quick google for 'c# xml xslt pdf', gave me [this link](http://www.codelathe.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/28/generate-pdf-from-cnet/) which may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RDLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155062.aspx) to define report. It can export it to PDF/Excel. You can export report to pdf and attach it to send email using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class. You can also print the report using Report Viewer tool.

Alternately you can also use Crystal Reports bundled with visual studio.